# Asp.net detailsview - get data after update

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a web page with an editable DetailsView.  After it is (successfully) edited, I need to use some of the edited fields to update some other tables in the database (in the code behind).  I tried to use the DetailsView.DetailItem in the DetailsView_ItemUpdated event code, but the DetailItem isn't available any more - it is null.  What's the best way to get at the updated field information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell what you're trying without seeing some code. How are you trying to access the updated information? You should be able to access the [DetailsViewUpdatedEventArgs Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.detailsviewupdatedeventargs_properties.aspx) in the ItemUpdated event by using the "e" parameter. You can see an example of this where the Keys property is accessed on [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.detailsviewupdatedeventargs.keys.aspx).